# On generation of Error 404 in webview - not redirecting to desired page

Tags: android, webview

Below code is not redirecting to specified link on generation of error 404, instead it's showing error page. Kindly have a look on below code.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                            String description, String failingUrl) {
    //Log.e(TAG," Error occured while loading the page at Url"+ failingUrl+"." +description);

    if (errorCode == 404) {
        // show Alert here for Page Not found
        view.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, noconnection.class);
        intent.putExtra("a", "mainactivity is source");
        startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured, please check network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
}
```

> Error Log:

```
05-14 09:54:36.655 5673-5673/com.hare.pat E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
05-14 09:54:36.885 5673-5673/com.hare.pat E/chromium: [ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(258)] Failed to init browser shader disk cache.
05-14 09:54:37.026 5673-5673/com.hare.pat E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

errorcode corresponds to an ERROR_* constant value, and not 404.

You should use `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (whose constant value is -14)  ( [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#) )

You can browse more list of constants [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) 
I have added the error constant here for reference.

```
/** Generic error */
public static final int ERROR_UNKNOWN = -1;
/** Server or proxy hostname lookup failed */
public static final int ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP = -2;
/** Unsupported authentication scheme (not basic or digest) */
public static final int ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_AUTH_SCHEME = -3;
/** User authentication failed on server */
public static final int ERROR_AUTHENTICATION = -4;
/** User authentication failed on proxy */
public static final int ERROR_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION = -5;
/** Failed to connect to the server */
public static final int ERROR_CONNECT = -6;
/** Failed to read or write to the server */
public static final int ERROR_IO = -7;
/** Connection timed out */
public static final int ERROR_TIMEOUT = -8;
/** Too many redirects */
public static final int ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP = -9;
/** Unsupported URI scheme */
public static final int ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME = -10;
/** Failed to perform SSL handshake */
public static final int ERROR_FAILED_SSL_HANDSHAKE = -11;
/** Malformed URL */
public static final int ERROR_BAD_URL = -12;
/** Generic file error */
public static final int ERROR_FILE = -13;
/** File not found */
public static final int ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = -14;
/** Too many requests during this load */
public static final int ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS = -15;
```

Comment: Still same, not redirecting

Comment: Can you put debugger point there and see what errorcode value you get?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626377/android-webview-error-failed-to-init-browser-shader-disk-cache and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013125/sysutils-applicationcontext-is-null-in-applicationstatus-webview... I think there are other issues other than `errorCode == 404`

Comment: Just saw it. I have clicked on a bad link to get errorcode 404. So maybe that's the reason it's showing this error

Comment: Then the errorcode should be something between -1 to -15. Try exploring more regarding this. And do note that the above receivederror method is `This method was deprecated in API level 23. `. You have to use `onReceivedError(WebView, WebResourceRequest, WebResourceError)` instead. And accept answer if solved :-)

Comment: replacing with old method reflected in not allowing to override 'onReceivedError'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144154/discussion-between-santosh-and-observer).